# Get pdf object in Mac application

Tags: objective-c, macos, safari

I am creating my first Mac app, where I want to print(Safari- web page) to my app. But I don't know how to get pdf file in my app. Can please anyone help me. Do I have to create app with any extension ? if yes which extension will be helpful?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: What have you done in your app so far?  Are you using a `WebView` or a `WKWebView` to display the web page?  Or, do you mean that you want to save a web page from Safari and have it load in your app as a PDF?

Comment: Thank you Michael, Yes second option, I want to save a web page from Safari and want to load in my app.

Comment: So is your question really something like: "if I save a PDF file from Safari, how can I open that PDF in my app?".

Comment: I add app in pdf option, and when we. click in Safari -> File -> Print -> PDF -> your app. So it is passing the pdf file to my app but I dont know how to get an object of pdf file in my app.

Answer (score 0):

I got one solution. I have to place my app in the "PDF Services" then if we go to Safari -> File -> Print -> PDF(options) -> (app). This will invoke us in a AppDelegate method 
`-(void)application:(NSApplication *)sender openFiles:(NSArray<NSString *> *)filenames` and here we get a pdf file.